# I want to delete part of a line in txt file using file hanling in perl

Tags: perl, file-handling

such that if the lines in input file are :

```
 abc !asdas 
 abc, sadasda
 abc.
```

the output file shoud be:

```
 abc
 abc,
 abc.
```

Comment: yes i want to keep abc and abc with ',' but delete everything in the line that comes after '!' or ','.
I have never used file handling in perl so all suggestions will be appriciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it.  You may need to adjust `split` if your data gets any different.  All it does now is split on space.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

open (my $in, '<', "in.txt") or die $!;
open (my $out, '>', "out.txt") or die $!;

while (<$in>) {
    my ($val) = split ' ';
    print $out "$val\n";
}

close ($in);
close ($out);
```

If I had to do this though, this is what I would do from the command line:

```
awk '{ print $1 }' in.txt > out.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

file.txt contains the text from your post.

Perl script:

```
use strict;
open(IN, 'file.txt');
while(<IN>){
   chomp;
   my(@elems) = split(/\s+/, $_);
   print $elems[0] . "\n";
}
```